# How does Hegel's idea of labor connect to idealism?

Tags: consciousness, hegel, idealism

Was Hegel a Marxist, in that, he also believed that labor had liberating and oppressive potential? How is the concept of idealism linked to labor in his view?

Comment: Hegel died in 1831 when Marx was 13, so no he was not a Marxist. Marx was a Hegel's follower who replaced his idealism with materialism, but see Ashton's [Hegel & Labour](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/hegel/txt/ashton.htm).

Comment: Labor is not a primary concept in Hegel's philosophy -- though it is in Marx.

Comment: Check out _The System of Needs_ in his _Philosophy of Right_ https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/hegel/works/pr/prcivils.htm#PRa195